# When creating a RestApi project, Laravel didn't generate the needed files

Tags: laravel, laravel-11

I'm a beginner in development and am currently creating my first RestfulApi project with Laravel. Although I created the project in the terminal using the `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel NameApp` command, Laravel did not generate middleware files, provider files, or the kernel.php, channels.php, or api.php files. I attempted to manually add these files, update Composer and Laravel from version 10 to 11, and change the composer.lock settings, but the application is not functioning. Despite adding two routes (`route::apiResource('something', SomethingController::class)`) in api.php, no routes are displayed when I use the PHP artisan route:list command. Please excuse my limited knowledge if something was obvious, as I am still learning and need your assistance.

I tried manually adding the missing files, updating Composer, requiring preprio/laravel-rest-sdk:"^4.0" in Composer, changing the composer.lock settings, installing axios with npm, and using php artisan make:provider and make:middleware to create the files I was missing.

Comment: A lot of those files are no longer created in Laravel 11. https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/releases talks about some of the changes, such as [api routing being opt-in instead of automatic](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/releases#opt-in-routing) and [middleware being moved to the framework](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/releases#middleware)

Comment: as a beginner i would recommend you first try to get you hands on laravel 9 or 10 . they have all the dir available and will be easy for you to learn